# How to skip request Angular if data loaded?

Tags: angular

I use http client to fetch data from server. How to skip request if data was loaded before?

I have the realization:

```
export class AppComponent {
  private cache = new Map();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.cache = new Map<number, Observable<any>>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.load(1).subscribe((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.load(2).subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.load(1).subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }, 5000);
  }

  load(id: number) {
    if (this.cache.has(id)) return this.cache.get(id);

    const observable = this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + id)
      .pipe(shareReplay(1));

    this.cache.set(id, observable);
    return observable;
  }
}
```

I could use shareReplay() but it worts only for one request. In my case request depends id. Also another one problem is I got 1 value twicw because there are two subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the response, and set it on your cache map as an observable

Also you wouldn't need the share replay

Could you try something like this?

```
  load(id: number) {
    if (this.cache.has(id)) return this.cache.get(id);

    return this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + id)
      .pipe(tap((r)=>this.cache.set(id, of(r))));

  }
```

Comment: Problem is that in sync part code I need to subscribe on load() always instead return data. As result I got the count of subscription equal to count of call load()

Comment: This example code would still return an observable that you could subscribe to

Comment: yes, but I got a lot of subscriptions in this case

Comment: I am not understanding exactly your use case. From the initial question, this solution would cache it perfectly

Comment: of(r).pipe(share())  <-- Is this what you need?

Comment: I mean `this get(data) { this.load(e) => {data.res = e;} return data; }`